# how can i assess the meta part of resource collection API in laravel?

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, api

**What I want to achieve**: want to access and print the meta part of the collection

**What I tried:**

```
$products = products::where('product_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
    ->where('product_status', 1)
    ->where('publish_status', 1)
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(8);
// dd($products);

$products->appends(array(
    'query' => Input::get('search_text')
));

return Searchmanager::collection($products)->additional([
    'meta' => [
        'min_mrp' => '100',
    ]
]);
```

**Here is my resource part:**

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return parent::toArray($request);
    //dd($this->meta) what i tried but not working
}
```

**Here is my response:**

```
 {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 37,
            "product_webid": "pmtrj0vwj4",
            "product_name": "Samsung Galaxy Note 9",
            "slug": "samsung-galaxy-note-9",
            "description": "demo",

        }
    ],
    "links": {
        "first": "https://mobileappdatabase.in/ecomv2/api/search?query=sam&page=1",
        "last": "https://mobileappdatabase.in/ecomv2/api/search?query=sam&page=1",
        "prev": null,
        "next": null
    },
    "meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "path": "https://mobileappdatabase.in/ecomv2/api/search",
        "per_page": 8,
        "to": 7,
        "total": 7,
        "min_mrp": "100"
    }
}
```

i have tried dd($request); , $this->meta , $this->meta['mn_mrp'] , $this->collection->meta not work for me please help me out.

[image: when i dd request]

Comment: Access from where? Print to where?

Comment: Thanks for your reply apokryfos i want to access this in  my function toArray($request) and then return to response. actually i want ti put some conditions here so i need that additional data to be accessed here

Comment: try dd($request) first

Comment: i have tried it but not work for me

Comment: it only provide me my posted prams not the result i sent in collection